# Looping through FTP folders to download files VBA?

Tags: internet-explorer, excel, ftp, permission-denied, vba

I'm trying to loop through an FTP that uses the following HTML for uploads (folder/files):

```
<pre>
<a href="/Example%20Folder/">Example Folder</a>
<a href="/Example%20File.xlsx">Example File.xlsx</a>
<a href="/Example%20Folder/Example%20File%20In%20Folder.xlsx">Example File In Folder.xlsx</a>
</pre>
```

My code attempts to loop through all folders (if present) on the site and download every file.  The issue is that after entering and then navigating **back** to the root directory, I receive the error 70 "Permission Denied."  The relevant code can be found below:

```
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim oFolder, oSubfolder, oFile, bButton, queue As Collection
Dim oFileName As String
Dim processed As Boolean
Dim processedList As String
Dim toPath As String
Dim fromPath As String
Dim HWNDsrc As Long

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set queue = New Collection

queue.Add IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")

Do While queue.Count > 0 
   Set oFolder = queue(1)
   Set bButton = Nothing
   queue.Remove 1

   If Right(oFolder, 1) = "/" Then 'Check if the link is a folder ***ERROR HERE
     IE.Navigate oFolder
     Do While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
     Do Until IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop 'readystate=4
     Set bButton = IE.Document.getElementById("goParent") 'Back button in browser
     Set oFolder = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")
   End If

  For Each oSubfolder In oFolder
    If Right(oSubfolder, 1) = "/" Then
      queue.Add oSubfolder
    End If
  Next oSubfolder

  For Each oFile in oFolder 
    If InStr(oFile, ".") > 0 Then 'Check if link is file
      oFileName = Replace(Right(oFile, Len(oFile) - InStrRev(oFile, "/")), "%20", " ")
      fromPath = DOWNLOADS_FOLDER & oFileName 'downloads_folder defined earlier
      toPath = DESTINATION_FOLDER & oFileName 'destination_folder defined earlier

      With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate oFile
      End With

      HWNDsrc = IE.HWND
      SetForegroundWindow HWNDsrc
      Sleep (1500)
      Application.SendKeys ("%s") 'Used because URLDownloadToFile can't handle FTP
      Do While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
      Do Until IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

      processed = True
      processedList = processedList & vbCrLf & _
                      oFileName

      If Len(Dir(toPath)) = 0 Then
        fso.MoveFile fromPath, toPath
      End If
    End If
  Next oFile

  If Not bButton Is Nothing Then 'If in subfolder, return to main directory
    With IE
      bButton.Click
      Do While .Busy: DoEvents: Loop
      Do Until .ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
    End With
  End If
Loop
```

After executing the bButton block of code, oFolder cannot be printed and returns the "Permission denied" error.  Is there any way to get around this issue?

Comment: Try capturing the url for the main directory and navigate directly, instead of the back button click?

Comment: @DavidZemens Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, no dice. Seems like each time the IE page is refreshed the queue objects are reset.  Going to try storing each folder link in an array and navigating to each page separately, instead of looping through HTML elements.

Comment: Store them in a dictionary instead of an array. They are optimized and you don't need to keep `ReDim` to resize them, etc. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is interested, @PatricK made me realize an error and I ended up resolving my issue by using the CStr() function, as below:

```
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim oFolder, oFile, bButton, queue As Collection
Dim oFileName As String
Dim EMAIL_BODY As String
Dim processed As Boolean
Dim processedList As String
Dim toPath As String
Dim fromPath As String
Dim HWNDsrc As Long

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set queue = New Collection
Set oFolder = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")

'Make sure there is something in the queue
For Each oFile In oFolder 
    If Right(oFile, 1) = "/" Or InStr(oFile, ".") > 0 Then
        queue.Add FTP_URL
        Exit For
    End If
Next oFile

Do While queue.count > 0
    IE.Navigate queue(1)
    Sleep (700)
    Set oFolder = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    Set bButton = Nothing
    queue.Remove 1

    For Each oFile In oFolder
        'Format name to allow downloads
        oFileName = Replace(Right(oFile, Len(oFile) - InStrRev(oFile, "/")), "%20", " ")
        fromPath = DOWNLOADS_FOLDER & oFileName
        toPath = DESTINATION_FOLDER & oFileName

        If InStr(oFile, ".") > 0 And Len(Dir(toPath)) = 0 Then 'Check if link is new file
            IE.Visible = True
            IE.Navigate oFile

            'Handle IE "Open", "Save", "Close" prompt
            Sleep (1500)
            HWNDsrc = IE.HWND
            SetForegroundWindow HWNDsrc
            Application.SendKeys ("%s") 'URLDownloadToFile does not work with FTP
            Sleep (1500)
            fso.MoveFile fromPath, toPath

            processed = True
            processedList = processedList & vbCrLf & _
                            oFileName
        ElseIf Right(oFile, 1) = "/" Then ' Check if link is subfolder
            queue.Add CStr(oFile) '**Converting to string prevents Permission Error
        End If
    Next oFile
Loop

IE.Quit
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your issue is within the FTP page, try modify below to suit your download. This is solely for demonstrating the link extraction process, have not implement the download and response to credential prompts from IE.

Below code will extract all files links and displays them, it stops recursing into folders when count is above **maxCount** (you may want to keep this for debug purposes).

```
Const maxCount = 20
Const sRootURL As String = "<Your FTP Site>" ' e.g. "ftp://ftp.kernel.org/"
Dim oIE As Object, oFolderLinks As Object, oFileLinks As Object

Sub IE_FTP()
    Set oFolderLinks = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList") ' .NET Runtime required
    Set oFileLinks = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList") ' .NET Runtime required
    Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    oIE.Visible = True ' For Debug Purposes
    oIE.Silent = True ' Disable Popups
    ExtractLinks sRootURL
    For i = 1 To oFileLinks.Count
        Debug.Print "[" & i & "] " & oFileLinks(i - 1)
        ' You may want to create and call a Download Sub for each of these file links
    Next
    Set oIE = Nothing
    oFileLinks.Clear
    Set oFileLinks = Nothing
    oFolderLinks.Clear
    Set oFolderLinks = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub ExtractLinks(sURL As String)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim oItem As Object, sLink As String, oLocalLinks As Object, i As Long

    If oFileLinks.Count > maxCount Then Exit Sub
    With oIE
        .Navigate2 sURL
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            Set oLocalLinks = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList") ' .NET Runtime required
            Do While .Busy
            Loop
            ' Add current URL to Folder Links
            If Not oFolderLinks.contains(sURL) Then
                oFolderLinks.Add sURL
            End If
            ' Extract all local links on this page
            For Each oItem In .Document.getElementsByTagName("A")
                sLink = CStr(oItem)
                If Not oLocalLinks.contains(sLink) Then
                    oLocalLinks.Add sLink
                End If
            Next
            For i = 0 To oLocalLinks.Count - 1
                sLink = oLocalLinks(i)
                If Right(sLink, 1) = "/" Then
                    ' Navigate to all Local Links that are not already in Folder Links
                    If Not oFolderLinks.contains(sLink) Then ExtractLinks sLink
                Else
                    ' sLink is not a folder, add this to File Links
                    If Not oFileLinks.contains(sLink) Then
                        oFileLinks.Add sLink
                    End If
                End If
            Next
            oLocalLinks.Clear
            Set oLocalLinks = Nothing
        Else
            Debug.Print "ERR(" & Err.Number & "):" & Err.Description & " | " & sURL
            Err.Clear
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I didn't actually end up using your code, but THANK YOU!!!  CStr() is actually all I needed to make my code work.